# What code can create evenly spaced circles within a circle in C++?

Tags: c++, graphics, geometry

I have been attempting to develop a program using GUI that creates a circle and then creates multiple circles based on User input, those circles should have the same size, evenly spaced, and must have a point touching the outer circle.

This is my code so far:

```
int PI = 3.14159265359;

int main(){
    srand(time(0));

    while(true){
        Point tl(0,0);           // to become top left  corner of window

        Simple_window win(tl,500,500,"Canvas");    // make a simple window

        Circle c0(Point(250, 250), 200);

        c0.set_color(rand()%243+23);  // adjust properties of poly
        win.attach(c0);
       int n;
       cout << "Enter Number of Cycles: ";
       cin >> n;
       if (n <= 0) break;
       int genrand = rand();
       int t = rand() * (2*PI);
//       int xc = rand() % 200, yc = rand() % 200;
       int r = 200*sin(PI/n)/(1 + sin(PI/n));
       int x = 250 + r * cos(t);
       int y = 250 + r * sin(t);
       Vector_ref<Circle>rc;
       Circle cr(Point(x,y),r);
       cr.set_color(rand()%243+23);
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
           rc.push_back(cr);
       }
       for(int k = 0; k < rc.size(); k++) win.attach(rc[k]);

       win.wait_for_button();       // give control to the display engine
       }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the issue is that no circles aside from the main circle appear in the output...

Comment: And? What's the problem?

Comment: As I corrected myself, the issue is that none of the inner circles are appearing...

Comment: Add Basic debugging: *print out* how many circles should be drawn, and how many are actually drawn. Compare against your expectations. Side note: do you know to how many digits your value of `PI` is accurate?

Comment: .. Another side note: your code does not compile for me. It probably needs a few headers. Please make it a [mcve].

Comment: my includes are include "Simple_window.h"    // get access to our window library
#include "Graph.h"            // get access to our graphics library facilities
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
using namespace std;
using namespace Graph_lib;   // our graphics facilities are in Graph_lib

Comment: Mr. Lexus, the code compiles on my end, I am using FLTK, however, only outer circle shows on the display

Comment: @RadLexus,  this is from  Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++

Comment: Please do not add code (or anything else) in comments. You can [edit] your question and add all that's missing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are learning the beginning of programming making a simple GUI with [Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) which is great! (here are the [includes](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/) ).

Now, you will need to pay attention to where you are creating and modifying the value of yours variables (objects) with respect to the cycles where you are using it. You are preparing just one `Circle cr` and them pushing back it several times to the vector `rc` inside the cycle. Just move the calculation of the coordinates and the creation of the Circle to inside the `for` cycle ... think about, and try again.